# Manage Columns : order by post_parent's title

Tags: custom-post-types, order, screen-columns

I have 2 custom post types : "industry" (page + hierarchical) and "product" (post + hierarchical). This allows me to use Industry for Product's post_parent.

On the Product manage screen, I have a custom column that displays the title of the product's post_parent, an industry. I would like to make that column sortable.

```
function column_orderby ( $vars )
{
    $output = array();

    switch ( $vars['orderby'] )
    {
        case 'industry':
/*
            NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE

            orderby post_parent's title
*/
            break;

        case 'product': // Custom column that just displays post_title differently
            $output = array(
                'orderby' => 'title'
            );
            break;
    }

    return array_merge($vars, $output);
}
add_filter('request', 'column_orderby');
```

I don't think I can merge any useful parameters. It has crossed my mind to use the `posts_join` and/or `posts_where` filters, but I'm not sure if this would work.

My question is, should I experiment with the hooks mentioned above or is there another way I'm not thinking of?

Cheers,